# OMNET++: How to obtain wireless signal power?

Tags: omnet++, rssi, inet, signal-strength

I am using the newly released INET 4.0 framework for OMNET++ and I would like to obtain the received signal strength value in a wireless host (of type AdhocHost). How may I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `INET` 4.0.0 the packet received by a module contains several [tags](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/developers-guide/ch-packets.html#packet-tagging). Between others there is `SignalPowerInd` tag. According to [SignalTag.msg](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/physicallayer/common/packetlevel/SignalTag.msg):

> This indication specifies the average analog signal power that was detected during receiving the packet.
> It may be present on a packet from the phyiscal layer to the application.

This tag is present in packet processing by a wireless MAC layer, for example:
[image]

And packet received by application layer contains `SignalPowerInd` too:

[image]

---

One can obtain the value of `SignalPowerInd` from received radio packet in any layer using standard API. For example, to obtain it in `UdpBasicApp` one should add in `UdpBasicApp.cc`:

```
#include "inet/physicallayer/common/packetlevel/SignalTag_m.h"
// ...

void UdpBasicApp::socketDataArrived(UdpSocket *socket, Packet *packet) {

   if (packet->findTag<SignalPowerInd>() != nullptr) {
       auto signalPowerInd = packet->getTag<SignalPowerInd>();
       auto rxPower = signalPowerInd->getPower().get();
       EV_INFO << "RX power= " << rxPower << "W" << endl;
   } 

   // process incoming packet
   processPacket(packet);
}
```

Comment: in my case the power is always 0mW. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65293303/unitdiskradiomedium-no-power-consumption-settings-omnetpp