# How to get the RSSI in the MAC layer also the Network layer by the Omnet++ 6 and the Inet 4.4 framework for a wireless multi radio interface nodes

Tags: omnet++, inet

By the Omnet++ 6 and then Inet 4.4 framework:

I want to simulate a WiFi network that includes some nodes, each node has several radio interfaces for example two radio interfaces,

1. Can I get the RSSI value when a packet is received in the MAC layer? If the answer is yes, how to get the RSSI value? Should the amount of the RSSI be calculated by each radio interface that received the packet?
2. How about in the network layer?

Please include the necessary code in addition to the explanation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Received Signal Strength Indicator (RSSI) is an estimated measurement of how well a device can hear, detect and receive signals from any wireless access point or Wi-Fi router. A person who is not known to me has recorded a negative score, I wish that person could answer the question instead of recording a negative score which is an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

**Ad. 1.** In MAC layer it is possible to get the power of the received signal - take a look at [OMNET++: How to obtain wireless signal power?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365240/omnet-how-to-obtain-wireless-signal-power/51378515#51378515). The RSSI is proportional to the power of the signal, however the IEEE 802.11 standard does not specify how the RSSI is related to that power. It is vendor specific.
**Ad. 2.** The power of received signal as well as the radio interface ID are available for developers in the network layer - in the same way as presented in the mentioned answer.